# Suggestions needed on tools and technologies to use for building a Facebook-like website

Tags: facebook, architecture

With so many tools and technologies lying around, I am looking for suggestions around the best ones (UI/server-side frameworks/database/CMS)  to use for building a web(site/app) similar to Facebook itself.

Details of the website cannot be revealed due to privacy concerns. But largely, the experience and interactions would be similar to what Facebook has (such as continuous feeds, groups, upload data/files, comments, etc.), just that it would be in a different domain.

Information (or links) on what technologies/frameworks are such sites/portals using will also be of great help!

Comment: I think your problem is one of cash and engineering resources, not technology.  What FaceBook has is the result of 10 years of engineering by hundreds (if not more) of programmers.

Comment: well, the algorithms and techniques may be, but what I'm looking for the technologies they use/evaluated for such a use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is [PHP](http://www.php.net).  But people likely imagine a LAMP stack.

Facebook has reengineered the front side and back side of PHP, as I understand it.  They use the [HipHop compiler](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) to cut the cost of execution of PHP.  And I don't know the details, but they have some kind of backside distributed database they use instead of PHP/LAMP traditional use of MySQL.
(See http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=24413138919 for a description of one of the mechanisms they use, Cassandra).

If you don't care about scale, you can skip these two steps and save a lot of engineering.

Comment: thanks! what about data storage?

Comment: I revised my answer to include some detail.

Comment: thanks! I will take a look at these in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

[Elgg](http://elgg.org/) is a great start. they have numerous plugins (some that even make it look very similar to facebook). I've seen some prototypes that where built in a few days that have tons of functionality